# Print Options Do Not Open

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, printing

I have an html file in google script with JS, trying to print using the following code. It opens the document without the print options, I still have to do the cmd+P to print. Any idea, please?

```
function printBadge() {
        var attendee = document.getElementById("info").value; 
        var fullName = "xxx";
        var snb = "xxx";
        var printFonts = "fonts";
        var printStyle = "style";
        var printArea = "badge info";

          w = window.open();
          w.document.write(printFonts + printStyle + printArea).html();
          w.document.close();
          w.focus();
          w.print();
          w.close();
         return false;
      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is this line `w.document.write(printFonts + printStyle + printArea).html();`. There is no function `.html()` associated to `document.write` and when you try to execute it, it fails there and so window gets stuck.

It needs to be `w.document.write(printFonts + printStyle + printArea)` without .html() function.

Hope it helps. Revert for any doubts.

Comment: Hi @Moustafa, if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. More here: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)